# Why doesn't the text size in a Win32 edit control change when the control's zoom factor changes?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using a multi-line edit control in a Win32 C++ app I'm developing.

I've set the zoomable extended style and confirmed that the zoom factor does change when using the mouse wheel over the edit box while CTRL is held down.  However, any text in the control stays the same size.

Before zooming:

[image: Before zooming]

After zooming:

[image: After zooming]

How I'm creating the edit control:

```
g_editControlHandle = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    L"EDIT",
    L"",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_NOHIDESEL,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    hwnd,
    editControlId,
    g_mainWindowClass.hInstance,
    nullptr
);
constexpr auto extendedStyles = ES_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL | ES_EX_CONVERT_EOL_ON_PASTE | ES_EX_ZOOMABLE;
SendMessage(g_editControlHandle, EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, extendedStyles, extendedStyles);
SetWindowSubclass(g_editControlHandle, FNEditControlProc, static_cast<int>(ChildId::EditControl), 0);
```

How I'm retrieving the zoom factor:

```
void UpdateZoomStatus()
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    Edit_GetZoom(g_editControlHandle, &numerator, &denominator);
    const auto zoom = static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(numerator) / static_cast<double>(denominator) * 100.0);
    std::wstringstream zoomText;
    zoomText << zoom << L"%";
    SendMessage(g_statusBarHandle, SB_SETTEXT, MAKEWPARAM(static_cast<WORD>(StatusBarField::Zoom), 0), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(zoomText.str().data()));
}
```

The sublass procedure for the edit control:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK FNEditControlProc(const HWND hWnd, const UINT uMsg, const WPARAM wParam, const LPARAM lParam, [[maybe_unused]] UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, [[maybe_unused]] DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CHAR && !g_insertMode)
    {
        if (!(wParam == VK_RETURN || wParam == VK_BACK || wParam == VK_DELETE || wParam == VK_TAB))
        {
            // If the selection length is 0, replace the character at the caret with the typed character, otherwise replace the selected text with the typed character.
            DWORD selectionStart;
            DWORD selectedEnd;
            SendMessage(hWnd, EM_GETSEL, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(&selectionStart), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&selectedEnd));
            if (const auto selectionLength = selectedEnd - selectionStart; selectionLength == 0)
            {
                const auto caretIndex = Edit_GetCaretIndex(hWnd);
                // ReSharper disable once CppTooWideScopeInitStatement
                const auto textLength = Edit_GetTextLength(hWnd);
                if (caretIndex < static_cast<DWORD>(textLength))
                {
                    auto text = new WCHAR[2];
                    text[0] = static_cast<WCHAR>(wParam);
                    text[1] = L'\0';
                    SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETSEL, caretIndex, caretIndex + 1);
                    SendMessage(hWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, true, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(text));
                }
                else
                {
                    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SendMessage(hWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, true, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&wParam));
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    const auto result = DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    if (uMsg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case VK_UP:
            case VK_DOWN:
            case VK_LEFT:
            case VK_RIGHT:
            case VK_HOME:
            case VK_END:
            case VK_PRIOR:
            case VK_NEXT:
            {
                PostMessage(GetParent(hWnd), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(static_cast<int>(ChildId::EditControl), FNN_SEL_CHANGE), MAKELPARAM(hWnd, 0));
                break;
            }

            case VK_INSERT:
            {
                g_insertMode = !g_insertMode;
                UpdateInsertModeStatus();
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (uMsg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        UpdateZoomStatus();
    }

    return result;
}
```

As far as I can tell, I'm not swallowing any messages other than those I intended to.

Comment: All you are doing is zooming the ratio, but you are not actually using the ratio. You likely have to manually apply the ratio to the Edit's font whenever the ratio changes. On a side note: why are you using `EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE` instead of passing the extended styles to `CreateWindowEx()` directly?

Comment: Because the zoom factor wasn't changing when I passed the extended styles in the `CreateWindowEx()` call.

Comment: You need to apply the zoom to the device context of the edit control. Also have a look at [Windowless Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-windowless-rich-edit-controls) and the messages of zoom for Notepad in Spy++.